# Asp.net using javascript, I have taken from Google maps how to save data to the database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDX1D37MapC2HfewVE0T3MXcUT4bstvHq8&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var geocoder;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
    }
    //Get the latitude and the longitude;
    function successFunction(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        codeLatLng(lat, lng)
    }

    function errorFunction() {
        alert("Geocoder failed");
    }

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }

    function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions:
                {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(
                     document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
                     );
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results)
                if (results[1]) {
                    //formatted address
                    alert(results[0].formatted_address)
                    //find country name
                    for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                        for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {
                            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                                //this is the object you are looking for
                                city = results[0].address_components[i];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // city data                  
                    alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)
                }
                else {
                    alert("No results found");
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Your Location"
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

2-3 hours, I'm looking on the internet and I try, but I did not get results. I'm trying another code block, latitude and longitude can save the database. This is not just what I wanted, and I want to save the city formatted address.

I opened issue in another forum, not responding.
I need a lot of help. Code could bring up here. This issue of homework project.

Comment: This is not related to sql-server. please use tags properly